# How to center an bootstrap object?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
            <h1 class="header text-center">
                <span>Получите видео-инструкцию</span>
                <strong class="text-uppercase">как управлять своим временем</strong>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I wrote this code, but the object is still on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `justify-content-center` on the row

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <h1 class="header text-center">
            <span>Получите видео-инструкцию</span>
            <strong class="text-uppercase">как управлять своим временем</strong>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
```